# Voltmeter reading over 63 amps with no load attached

Tags: current, current-measurement, load, meter

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Please see the attached pictures.  I am new to electrical stuff and experimenting.  The meter in the attached pic shows over 63 amps with ZERO load attached.  Is this meter damaged?

[image: high amps with no load]

Comment: It looks like you are shorting your battery via the ammeter. It is strongly recommended to learn about different electronic equipment before trying to use it.

Comment: I have watched over a dozen videos with this exact meter, and that's how it's always hooked up

Comment: Voltmeters measure volts; ammeters measure amps.

Comment: Show the back of the device and/or tell us it's name/part number or share it's manual.

Comment: Yidiele seems to be the brand-name, I added a pic of the rear of the meter

Comment: You are measuring the maximum current that the little 9V battery can produce. but it cannot produce 63.3A, it might produce 63.3mA. Your battery is almost dead by shorting it with your current measurement. A new 9V alkaline battery can probably produce 300mA for a few seconds then it will be dead.

Comment: I meant the view of where the wires are connected

Comment: Battery is independent. It supply only the 'board'. What if you short black and red wire?

Comment: i posted a pic of the wiring in the back.  I am NOT, I repeat, NOT trying to MEASURE anything with this step, I am just trying to get power to the meter itself, so BOTH readings right now should be ZERO with nO LOAD attached.

Comment: OK, I found a similar meter with somewhat clear schematic diagram [on AE](https://www.aliexpress.us/item/2255800096681514.html). But it does not describe the wires unfortunately. So it looks like you have correctly powered on the meter. I guess you just need to connect the rest to see a meaningful result.

Comment: looks like there is some debris on the board where HKS is printed ... it may be shorting the two traces

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you have connected the meter incorrectly.

Someone has gone the the trouble of [writing up how many of those common voltmeter/ammeters work.](https://electroson.com/documentos/D_MD9059_0_MD9059%20DISPLAY%20LED_DOCUMENTACI%C3%93N.pdf)

Your meter appears to be one that expects an external current shunt as shown in this image from the linked pdf:

[image]

You have a 9V battery connected where the diagram shows a buck regulator to power the meter.

In that configuration, you have to connect the other three wires to be able to measure current.

The modules measure current by measuring the voltage drop across the shunt.  You do not appear to have a shunt for current measurement connected.

Since you have left the shunt connections (black and yellow) disconnected, there is a voltage appearing across them that the meter reads as a high current.

---

Wire your meter according to the manufacturers instructions rather than according to random YouTube videos.

Comment: I have it "half right" now. I hooked up a shunt, 24vdc lamp and bench-top supply.  When bench top supply is off, light is off, meter reads zero's correctly. But when I turn ON the bench supply, meter goes back to 63 amps and no volts...benchtop supply does indicate 24vdc, .02 amps and light comes on (see 2 more pics above)

Comment: @MatthewNeesley please also make sure the shunt is the correct resistance for the meter. If the resistance was much too high the current reading would also be much too high.

Comment: ok thanks very much i will investigate the shunt specification

Comment: i suppose the shunt comes with the meter so there is no chance that you used the wrong shunt...

Answer (score 2):

This is, I think, the relevant diagram from the [link](https://www.aliexpress.us/item/2255800096681514.html) provided by Eugene Sh. in the comments [image]

So you need to provide power between the thin red and yellow wires and the thick black wire, and leave the thin black wire open. The meter will measure the voltage on the C terminal of the shunt vs. the A terminal (ground) to determine the current through the load (low side sense). The yellow wire is to measure the voltage, which you have connected to the shunt.

If you want to use the 9V battery rather than power it from the measured voltage, you would use this wiring diagram:

[image]

Again, note that the shunt is in the LOW side (and the meter supply *must* be galvanically isolated from the other supply -- which a battery is).

Note which terminals are to be used in shunt (inboard vs. outboard) or you will add unnecessary inaccuracy.

The meters work like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftUJhG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There is a resistive voltage divider on the voltage input (yellow wire) and an amplifier on the current input (thick red wire).

Comment: That would make a lot of sense then! If this is the correct wiring, then Matthew has got the yellow and black wires mixed up, so the meter is seeing the shunt voltage as the power supply voltage (about 0 volts) and the power supply voltage as the shunt voltage (very high)

Answer (score 1):

FOUND IT! 
I was using the right shunt, but the previous diagram someone had posted was slightly incorrect. 
I have finally found the RIGHT one, and now all is good. :) 
The current draw is only 0.02 amps (shown on the bench supply) and the meter can't read that fine a measurement, but I'm happy. 
I've learned some useful info.
[image]

Comment: Yes Spehro, that's the diagram I used right before posting my final answer.

Comment: Not very accurate on the voltage. Did you adjust the trimpot? Some of those alligator leads are incredibly bad.

Comment: Today I learned what side of the "crocodile vs. alligator" debate @SpehroPefhany falls!

Comment: @SimonFitch So bad they may not even see you later. In the ones I had the maker stripped the wire, pushed the (few and thin) bare unplated copper strands back over the PVC and then crimped over that mess. Even continuity was dubious and huge voltage drop. I bought some nice [Keystone](https://www.keyelco.com/userAssets/file/M65p56.pdf) clips and made soldered leads with decent (600V 200°C AWG20) colo(u)red silicone wires.